# How can we configure a custom domain for Lightning Experience?

Tags: custom-domain, mydomain, cross-domain, domain-layer, enhanced-domains

We know that we can configure a custom domain for an Experiience Cloud site, but can we do that for Lightning Experience? In other words, instead of working from http://mydomainname.my.salesforce.com, can we work from http://mydomainname.com?

Answer (score 2):

You have [Options to Serve a Custom Domain](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_mgmt_domain_config_options.htm&type=5) in Salesforce. You'll want to read the entire article, plus the other article if you choose to use a [Naked Domain](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=domain_mgmt_naked_domains.htm&type=5&language=en_US) (such as `mydomainname.com` versus `www.mydomainname.com`). Not all DNS servers support the former, so you'll need to check with your provider. You just need to [Add a Domain](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=domain_mgmt_add.htm&type=5&language=en_US) (Setup > Domains > Add a Domain), and set up the configuration there, then you need to add a CNAME to your DNS entry, which will be in the form of `[YourFQDN].[Your18charOrgId].live.siteforce.com`, such as `www.mydomainname.com.00D000000000123AAA.live.siteforce.com`. Other options are available, which I won't get in to here, as the documentation goes into a lot more detail.

Comment: I think the OP is asking if the full platform (eg `https://abc.my.salesforce.com`) can use a custom domain, these links are about force.com sites

Comment: @JeffKranz You can customize almost any feature with Domains, including Salesforce itself, Site.com, and Communities. The documentation states: *You can configure domains and their site associations to suit your organization’s unique needs. For example, you can set up a single domain to host your Experience Cloud, Lightning Platform, and Site.com sites. Or perhaps you want a single site on more than one domain.*

Comment: Very interesting to see that it mentions Lightning Platform in that blurb. The rest of the documentation is very specific to site.com / Experience Cloud. We explored custom domains for the platform years ago and hit a dead end, but that's not to say it isn't possible. Just haven't seen or heard of it anywhere.

Comment: @JeffKranz It's really rare, but I recall seeing at least one instance of a company that did that. It was really impressive, actually. They used branding to make it look like a completely different app. I wish I had a production account for myself just so I could play with it.